# HTML5 video behavior on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-video, mobile-webkit

I am building a site where I have several `<video>` elements (looped animations) that act as part of my design (not as an actual video). This works quite well in desktop browsers, yet I am in trouble on mobile devices.
When I display the site on Android or iOS devices (ie. mobile webkit) I will get the OS's video player appearance and the videos will open in some sort of popup when I click them. I do know that I can bypass the autoplay restrictions by doing sth like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var pElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    pElement.load();
    pElement.play();
};
```

But this will again open the video(s) in a seperate window...

Does anyone know of a possibility to emulate / enable desktop-like behavior on mobile devices? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Markup is basic `<video>`-syntax btw:

```
<video autoplay loop>
    <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="vid.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="vid.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the html code for video tag which are you using?

Comment: @andriy.budzinskyy Added the markup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure about Android but [iOS devices can't run multiple video streams simultaneously](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> **Multiple Simultaneous Audio or Video Streams**
>
> Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single
>   audio or video stream at any time. Playing more than one video—side by
>   side, partly overlapping, or completely overlaid—is not currently
>   supported on iOS devices. Playing multiple simultaneous audio streams
>   is also not supported. You can change the audio or video source
>   dynamically, however. See “Replacing a Media Source Sequentially” for
>   details.

Comment: Do you know if there's a possibility to "trick" the placeholder for a single video?

Comment: I tried something similar and was never able to work around this limitation.

Comment: I think ios doesn't like autoplay or loop because of user bandwidth. It's really hard to get an audio file to play in the background the way the the browser works.  I don't really know of a workaround but would be interested.

Comment: @Blynn: Can't you bypass the autoplay-restriction of an `<audio>` just the way I am bypassing the `<video>` autoplay-restriction in my question?

Comment: I've tried bypassing it with javascript, html, and css but it appears Apple will not allow that.  You can make it happen on click but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, Android or iOS devices (ie. mobile webkit) are not able to run video as you are wanting . Video will open in a default video player of device.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube uses a mov or mp4 with ios to load the native look and feel for videos, or it links out to their app to play the video since it's installed on every ios device.

Comment: That's an interesting point, never thought about looking at how "the big ones" handle this. Web-based YouTube and vimeo videos on Android will open in the external player as well unfortunately though, is it possible to watch inline YouTube videos on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `windows.onload` to bypass autoplay? If I remember correctly setting the `preload` tag to none

```
<video src="vid.mov" preload=”none”></video>
```

should work.

Also, have you tried using the [Video For Everybody](http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/) approach? With that should be able to get the video to play in the web page rather than by the phone's OS, that way I believe you can achieve the same effect on supported devices.

**EDIT:** In regards to [j08691's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices/9764151#9764151), an alternative approach for iPhones could be to design a simple web viewer app for the site for iPhone which has a [workaround](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/) for the no-multiple video playing problem.

Comment: As far as I have experienced mobile devices will ignore the preload attribute of `<video>` elements (therefore the Javascript-"hack"). Video for everybody unfortunately serves me a file for download on my handheld. The app is probably a very good idea, but not an option in my case. Thanks for your effort, though.

Comment: hmmm, so you're giving up on this? I don't really know why the app is an option, but have you been able to produce it on android? Also I've heard of native interaction to ios from javascript. And if you really need it very badly, you can use a video to gif converter. There're many of them online. Good luck

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to build a mechanism that I can reuse in different situations lateron (i.e. putting it into a jQuery-plugin). For the site in question I can always find a workaround, yet it would be nice to know if there's a *one-fits-all* approach (which seems to be not existent at the moment). Thanks for the input.