# How can I make my embedded videos play in place on Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, video, html5-video, kindle-fire

I'm not sure if this is an Android situation or just a Kindle Fire situation, but I have HTML5 videos which play fine on normal browsers but insist on playing full screen on the Kindle. They also won't autoplay, I need to manually tap to play.

Here is the `video` snippet from my BackboneJS template:

```
<!-- "Video For Everybody" http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
<video class="video_main"  width="548" height="393" poster="<%= APP._rootDir %>assets/video/spinner.gif">
    <source src="<%= APP._rootDir %>assets/video/<%= APP._subdirectory %>/<%= media.data.location %>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<%= APP._rootDir %>assets/video/<%= APP._subdirectory %>/<%= media.data.location %>.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="<%= APP._rootDir %>assets/video/<%= APP._subdirectory %>/<%= media.data.location %>.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="548" height="393">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['<%= escape(APP._rootDir) %>assets%2Fvideo%2Fspinner.gif',{'url':'<%= escape(APP._rootDir) %>assets%2Fvideo%2F<%= APP._subdirectory %>%2F<%= media.data.location %>.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}">
        <img alt="<%= media.data.title %>" src="<%= APP._rootDir %>assets/video/spinner.gif" width="548" height="393" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">
    </object>
</video>
```

Each video is available in `.mp4`, `.flv`, `.webm`, and `.ogv`

How can I force the videos to play in their container element without going full-screen? I'm using jQuery to trigger the `play()` event.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices for the sad fact that it does not seem to be possible.....

Answer (score -1):

Try 3gp video files instead of mp4,flv and so on.Because almost every types of mobiles will accept this format.

**Utilize these links.**

http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp

http://daily3gp.com/vids/motorcycle_wipesout_explodes.3gp