# RTSP Protocol or HTML5 Video Tag?

Tags: mobile, cordova, html5-video, rtsp

Currently in full development of a mobile application video sharing (based on PhoneGap), I hesitate about the method used to send / play videos on mobile. So I have a choice between using the HTML5 video tag (which apparently require an additional plugin so that there was no problem in android), and the establishment of an RTSP streaming server, which I think the native video player will be directly launch.

I want to know what would be the best solution to watch these videos without losing quality with the ability to navigate the time of the video.

Thank you,
Yeppao

Comment: Even content that is not streamed will be opened by the native player, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. and for you, which one of this two solutions is the best choice ?

Comment: If you can afford the streaming in terms of money and maintenance go for the streaming.

Comment: Ok, can you post it in answer box, and i'll check it like a good answer. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both streamed videos and embedded `<video>` elements will open in the native player (at the time of writing at least) and you won't be able to display video inline. See **[this recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices)**.

So, at least to me, this boils down to the question if you can afford the streaming (both in terms of costs and maintenance) since a streamed video will always offer a better user experience (in case the streaming works properly...) than a downloaded one.