# Show controls while HTML5 video is playing

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, html5-video

Is there a way to show the controls after a video has started playing. Basically, I'm playing a video with play(), and I want the controls to stay up for a few seconds. Currently (at least on my Android device), the controls fade once the video starts.

Toggling the controls attribute doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 video on Android (iOS too) is not opened inline but in the native player (i.e. outside the browser), so the `<video>`-tag attributes have no control over what is going to happen in the player.

I don't know if it's possible to "hack" / set-up the native player so I guess you'll have to do research on that. I don't know of any way to remotely influence the behavior of the Android application unfortunately. In case you find out something it would be nice if you could let me know btw.

Also see **[a recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000624/html5-video-behavior-on-mobile-devices)** (which is rather discouraging unfortunately).

Comment: Sorry, question is regarding where video does play inline (tablets).

Comment: @dc- How do you get the video to play inline? Will an Android tablet play video in the browser?

Comment: I believe Android 3+ plays inline by default.

Comment: @dc- Just tried watching a `<video>` in 3.0 AVD and it didn't open inline but in the native player as well. Are you sure you are able to do this? What device are you using and how do you embed the video?

Comment: @m90- doh sorry, 3.1+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711078/html5-video-element-on-android

Comment: @dc- thanks for the link! But isn't that just referring to the fact that `<video>` implementation was quite buggy before that (i.e. some Android devices wouldn't be able to play `<video>` at all up to 3.1)? In any case, I'll fire up a new AVD right now!

Comment: @dc- Hmm, a newer AVD crashes when I press play.... So at least there seems to be a difference :)